# Changing words on my website whilesomeone is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, html, apache, phpmyadmin

How can I set words on a page, in my case the words: "sign up/login" change to "profile" when someone is logged in on my site?

I also want to add words that say, "welcome (profile name)

(Website is in html5 and the page has a .php extension, on windows 10 if that helps)

Comment: You simply replace the "login" with the "user name" in the menu when a user have logged in .... and if you want to know how, update your question with a minimal working code snippet so we see how it looks like

Comment: Please read 'How to ask a question?' before asking one: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LGSon but how? You just restated my question? I want to know the code to change the words, so like if someone is logged in, then output this words instead.

Comment: As unprecise your question is in terms of example code, as unprecise my answer is: use an `if` statement.

Comment: Anything we post not knowing how your code looks as of now will be a simple guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplest sort of way to show you what to do:

```
<?php
session_start(); // initialize session to store username to. always do this at the very start of your scripts that use sessions

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // do some validation ...

    // get user from data source like mysql database with username/password combo
    $valid_user = [
        'username' => 'demo',
        'password' => 'demopass',
        'full_name' => 'Some Name'
    ];

    if($_POST['password'] == $valid_user['password']) {

        $_SESSION['user_session_id'] = session_id();
        $_SESSION['full_name'] = $valid_user['full_name'];

    }

}


if(isset($_SESSION['user_session_id'])) {

    echo 'Hello ' . $_SESSION['full_name'] .'!';

} else {

    $form = '<form method="post">';
    $form .= '<input type="text" name="username" value="">';
    $form .= '<input type="text" name="password" value="">';
    $form .= '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">';
    $form .= '</form>';
    echo $form;

}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for actually answering :)